# Alineamiento dentro de nav

Tags: css, bootstrap, nav

Buenas, estoy intentando crear este `nav` y quiero que mi logo se quede en la izquierda, y los enlaces caigan a la derecha, pero soy novato y no encuentro nada. Podéis ayudarme? Gracias

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md menu">

  <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">
    <img src="img/logo_cabecera.jpg" alt="Checan | Educación canina">
  </a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerMenu" aria-controls="navbarTogglerMenu" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerMenu">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
     <li class="nav-item active">
       <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home<span class="sr-only">
         (current)</span></a>
     </li>
     <li class="nav-item">
       <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
     </li>
     <li class="nav-item">
       <a class="nav-link" href="#">Disabled</a>
     </li>
     </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio Marcos!, te invito a realizar el [tour] para 
conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Con respecto a la realización de preguntas que estas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas excelentes respuestas, **es muy importante leer [ask]** en base a este documento modifica tu pregunta, es recomendable agregar lo que has intentado, saludos!

Comment: la última, me la descargué ayer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veo que utilizas la version 4 de Bootstrap, puedes agregarle un `ml-auto` a tu `navbar-nav`

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md menu">

  <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">
    <img src="img/logo_cabecera.jpg" alt="Checan | Educación canina">
  </a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerMenu" aria-controls="navbarTogglerMenu" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerMenu">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav ml-auto"> <-- Aquí ponemos ml-auto
     <li class="nav-item active">
       <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home<span class="sr-only">
     (current)</span></a>
     </li>
     <li class="nav-item">
       <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
     </li>
     <li class="nav-item">
       <a class="nav-link" href="#">Disabled</a>
     </li>
     </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Puedes ver un ejemplo funcional [aquí](https://codepen.io/kacospro/pen/ZvmNmq)

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta. En el ejemplo funcional de esta página sí que me sale a la derecha, pero cuando lo pongo en mi código, me sale a la izquierda. No lo entiendo la verdad.